# How to hide one div and show another div using button onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div in my html file. I want to hide the 1st div and show another div on html input button `onclick` event.

Here is my code,

```js
function switchVisible() {
  if (document.getElementById('Div1') !== undefined) {
    if (document.getElementById('Div1').style.display == 'Block') {
      document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'Block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'Block';
      document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#Div2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="" onclick="javascript:switchVisible();" />
```

But it's not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: couple of things, change "Block" to "block" and ensure that your div ID's are correct, they are case sensitive

Comment: Also, remove *javascript:* from the onclick

Comment: Since you've added the jQuery tag in your post, why not use `$('#Div1').hide(); $('#Div2').show();` and vice versa

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1) Inside onclick, you don't have to use "javascript:", that is implied.

2) You check for "display: block", I always check for "display: none" (Because the display can also be "inline-block", etc.)

Try this:

```js
function switchVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('Div1')) {

                if (document.getElementById('Div1').style.display == 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
}
```

```css
#Div2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="Div2">Div 2</div>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Click" onclick="switchVisible();"/>
```

Comment: how to add transition while toggling divs?

Comment: Instead of JS changing the 'style.display', you could make it change/switch/toggle some classname. In your CSS, you could add transitions to those.  Alternatively, you can use jQuery's animate() function to do this. Have a look at their documentation.

Answer (score 5):

As it is tagged with jQuery, here's the simple jQuery answer

```
$('body').on("click touchstart", "#Button1", function(e){
   $("#Div1, #Div2").toggle();
});
```

use on to listen for the id #Button, I've used both click and touchstart to make it mobile friendly, and then used toggle() which sets the state of the display: to the opposite to what it is now. So if it was display:none, it becomes display:block, if it was display:block it becomes display:none

Comment: It is tagged with jQuery, however user is clearly using pure JS.

Comment: Did not seem to be any point in answering the same result as others using pure JS when it had already been done.  Not in to duplicating effort.  I just looked at what the OP (the important one in this equation) asked for.

realistically, (s)he only had a spelling mistake, spelling "Block" and not "block".  

Sorry for you that you feel aggrieved at a qualified answer to a quested question.

Comment: I am actually more for your answer. I was just stating that yes he tagged it as jQuery when it shouldn't be. I'll upvote you to just show that I'm sincere. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById('Div1'),
    div2 = document.getElementById('Div2');
function switchVisible() {
  if(!div1) return;
  if (getComputedStyle(div1).display == 'block') {
    div1.style.display = 'none';
    div2.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    div1.style.display = 'block';
    div2.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
document.getElementById('Button1').addEventListener('click', switchVisible);
```

```css
#Div2 {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="Div2">Div 2</div>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Click me" />
```

---

However, this approach may be better:

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
function switchVisible() {
  wrapper.classList.toggle('switched');
}
document.getElementById('Button1').addEventListener('click', switchVisible);
```

```css
#wrapper > :last-child {
  display: none;
}
#wrapper.switched > :last-child {
  display: block;
}
#wrapper.switched > :first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
</div>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Click me" />
```

Comment: @AndyKillen The child combinator is faster than the descendant one. So I won't remove it just to save a byte.

Comment: Please give me a link to where it details this as being faster. It makes no logical sense in this context.

Comment: @AndyKillen `#wrapper.switched :first-child` first gets all `:first-child` elements, and then for each one it checks if there is a `#wrapper.switched` ancestor. `#wrapper.switched > :first-child` only checks each one's parent. And of course it's faster to check only the parent than checking all ancestors.

Comment: Ah, now I see your reasoning, your thinking that the divs will have a whole host of elements nested inside them, where I was thinking its just gonna be some sort of background image or something else equally un-complicated.  thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

you might wanna try this..

```js
    function switchVisible() {
     var div1=document.getElementById('Div1');
     var div2=document.getElementById('Div2');
     
      if (div1 !== undefined && div2 !== undefined) {
       div1.style.display = div2.style.display === '' ? 'none' : div2.style.display === 'none' ? 'none' : 'block';
       div2.style.display = div1.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
      }
    }
```

```css
#Div1{
 display: block;
 background: blue;
}

#Div2 {
  display: none;
  background: red;
}

.divs
{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Hide" onclick="switchVisible();" />

<div id="Div1" class="divs"> </div>
<div id="Div2" class="divs"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some syntax errors in your code. This one is working:

```js
function switchVisible() {
    if (document.getElementById('Div1') !== undefined) {

        if (document.getElementById('Div1').style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#Div1 {
    display:none;
}
#Div1 {
    background: red;
}
#Div2 {
    background: green;
}
#Div1, #Div2 {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Div1"></div>
<div id="Div2"></div>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="" onclick="javascript:switchVisible();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the click event through html. Add an event listener like `document.getElementById ("Button1").addEventListener ("click", switchVisible, false);`

See working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bevanr01/gmkconLw/