# Swap through div boxes

Tags: jquery, html, css, swipe

I created this:

https://jsfiddle.net/1qsoL695/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="select">
        <div>ONE</div>
        <div>TWO</div>
        <div>THREE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background: orange;
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
}

#select {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
}

#select div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 130pt;
    margin: 0;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("#select")
    .on('swiperight',  function(){
        divs.eq(i).toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 250, function() {

            i++;

            if(i > 2) { i = 0; }

            divs.eq(i).toggle('slide', {
                direction: 'left'
            }, 230);

        });

    })
    .on('swipeleft',  function(){
        divs.eq(i).toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 250, function() {

            i--;

            if(i < 0) { i = 2; }

            divs.eq(i).toggle('slide', {
                direction: 'right'
            }, 230);

        });


    });
```

You can swipe a number to display the next/previous one.

It is supposed to work on mobile screens, and already does, my question is, is there any more beautiful way to achieve the same result? My code seems very inconvenient.

Any help or tip appreciated.

Comment: It should be SWIPE through div boxes, not swap...

Comment: I think you should try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

i guess this will be the more convenient way for what you are looking:

[How to hide one div and show another div using button onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981198/how-to-hide-one-div-and-show-another-div-using-button-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS3 transforms and classes instead of JavaScript animation to swap between the divs. This approach would offer you greater performance and require less code, as all your JavaScript would have to do would be toggling an 'active' class to show the required div (positioning it on screen and hiding the inactive divs positioning them off screen).