# After click on same button show next image div at a time and hide current image div in javascript html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using Javascript, Html5, Jquery and Css. Right now I have three image div and I want to show one image div after click on button and I want to show next div after click on same button and hide current div.

right now i am using this code:
Css Code:

```
#Div2 {
    display: none;
}
#Div3 {
    display: none;
}
```

Html Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Click" onclick="switchVisible();"/>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div id="Div1">
                <canvas id="canvas1" class="img-responsive center-block" style="float:left"></canvas>  
            </div>
            <div id="Div2">
                <canvas id="canvas2" class="img-responsive center-block" style="float:left"></canvas>   
            </div>
            <div id="Div3">
                <canvas id="canvas3" class="img-responsive center-block" style="float:left"></canvas>    
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Java Script Code:

```
 function switchVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('Div1')) {
                if (document.getElementById('Div1').style.display === 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('Div3').style.display = 'none';
                }
                else if (document.getElementById('Div2').style.display === 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('Div3').style.display = 'none';

                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('Div3').style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
        }
```

This code is working fine for two image div but it is not working for the third image.I've taken help from this link:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981198/how-to-hide-one-div-and-show-another-div-using-button-onclick)

Now I have three image div but right now I am showing one image div at a time after click on button.

[image]

I want to show next image div after click on button and hide current image div.I told earlier I am using three image div. my motive to show image is as rotating.
Please give me some idea about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you could do this like this:

```
function switchVisible() {
    $(".img-responsive").parent().each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":visible")) {
            $(".img-responsive").parent().hide();
            if ($(this).next().length) {
                $(this).next().show();
            } else {
                $($(".img-responsive")[0]).parent().show();
            }

            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

You can use `prev()` instead of `next()` for going back.

```
 function switchVisibleRevert() {
    $(".img-responsive").parent().each(function(index){
        if($(this).is(":visible")) {
            $(".img-responsive").parent().hide();
            if ($(this).prev().length) {
                $(this).prev().show();
            } else {
                $($(".img-responsive")[$(".img-responsive").length-1]).parent().show();//show last element
            }

            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of ::if ($(this).next().length) {},

Comment: This is checking if there is anymore elements after "Div" element, if there isn't it will show the first one: $($(".img-responsive")[0]).parent().show(); In other words it is checking if this is the last div element.

Comment: Can we change the order of display div. I want to show last div in first time.And it should be start from last div.If it is possible then please let me know.

Comment: Just change your css so Div1 and Div2 is set to `display: none;` and Div3 is visible.

Comment: I am following above your code not mine code. So right now i am using SwitchVisible() function.

Comment: that's correct but you still using your css code to hide two div's (Div2 and Div3)?

Comment: Yes, You are right but sorry for miss communication. I want to show and hide div opposite direction. If right now show div left to right then i want right to left.

Comment: You can use `prev()` instead of `next()` for going back. Highly recommend reading documentation [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the conditional statements.

```
        if (document.getElementById('Div1')) {
            if (document.getElementById('Div1').style.display === 'none') {
                document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('Div3').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('Div2').style.display === 'none') {
                document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('Div3').style.display = 'none';

            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('Div3').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
```

The first conditional statement is setting the display property for Div1 to block. On the next call the second condition sets Div2 to block and Div1 to none again...so on the next call condition 1 is evaluated as true again, because Div1 was set to 'none' in the second condition.

You might try removing the 'else' and adding another else if condition that checks to see if Div2 == 'block', you know that if Div2 is set to .block' that the next image to be shown is image 3:

```
         if (document.getElementById('Div1')) {
            if (document.getElementById('Div1').style.display === 'none') {
                document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('Div3').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('Div1').style.display === 'block') {
                document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('Div3').style.display = 'none';

            }
            else if (document.getElementById('Div2').style.display === 'block')
            {
                document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('Div3').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
```

It might be simpler to initialise a counter to keep track of which image is being shown since each Div has a unique ID and sequential value.

Comment: I also tried this one trick, But last condition runs at a one time. Only first and second condition runs again and again by click on button.