# How do i hide a certain style when i click on a button and display a different style

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#logo {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

#logocaption {
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

#page1caption {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#next1 {
 background-color: transparent;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: solid 3px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px 50px 20px;
}

button:focus { 
 outline:0 !important; 
}

#next1:hover {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Template One</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="author" content="Carl Hansen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/MEDIAQ/mediaqueries.css">
  <script src="button.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <title>Web4Ever</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="page1">
    <div id="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"></div>
    <h1 id="logocaption">THE FUTURE <br> IS WEIRD</h1>
    <br>
    <p id="page1caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod <br>
    luctus tristique. Proin vel consectetur feugiat sed adipiscing.</p>
    <button id="next1">Next  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
   </div>

   <div class="page2">
    
   </div>

   <div class="page3">
    
   </div>

   <div class="page4">
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[When i click on my button i want to hide my current style and display another style that was previously hidden. Heres what i want to happen when i click the first button it will hide #page1 and display #page2 so on and so on. while i havent clicked on the buttons on seperate pages the other pages are hidden until i click them so its basically like a carousel in a complicated way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrfl3.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add some code snippets?

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708928/after-click-on-same-button-show-next-image-div-at-a-time-and-hide-current-image) , **hope this is helpful :)**

Answer (score 1):

i think you need `jQuery RemoveClass`

on your button click event remove class you dont want...

for eg:

```
<div id="mycontent"> My content</div>
<button id="someEvent">Next</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#someEvent").on('click', function(){
       $("#mycontent").removeClass('class_name') /* if you want to remove some style under class */
       $("#mycontent").addClass('class_name') /* if you want to show or add class */
    })
</script>
```

Comment: do i add that in my javascript file?

Comment: how do i include jquery? sorry been into this only like 2 weeks

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  include this into your HTML

Comment: when i put ur javascript code i get this error {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 72,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: this error due to jquery not defined. my answer was udpated check it.. before writing your script initiate jquery

Comment: @carl hansen  you're getting that error because you need to call the jquery library inside a script tag: <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

Comment: so i have to put 2 jquery script tags?

Comment: im using bootstrap i have jquery on it

Comment: then simply try addClass/removeClass

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with your code and I've done it the following way using jquery. You can see that I'm using click event on the buttons to show/hide pages.

```js
            $(function () {
                $('.page-block').hide();
                $('#page1').show();
                $(".btn").click(function (e) {
                    var pageId = $(e.target).data('target');
                    $('.page-block').hide();
                    $('#' + pageId).show();
                });
            });
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.c-btn {
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Template One</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Carl Hansen">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
            crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Web4Ever</title>

    </head>
       <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 page-block text-center" id="page1">
                    <h3>Page 1</h3>
                    <p id="page1caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod <br> luctus tristique. Proin vel consectetur feugiat sed adipiscing.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 page-block text-center" id="page2">
                    <h3>Page 2</h3>
                    <p id="page2caption">Page 2, Page 2, Page 2d <br> Page 2e. Proin vel consectetur feugiat sed adipiscing.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 page-block text-center" id="page3">
                    <h3>Page 3</h3>
                    <p id="page3caption">Page 3it amet, consectetuPage 3elit, sed do eiusmod <br> luctus tristique. Proin vel consectetur feugiat sed adipiscing.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 page-block text-center" id="page4">
                    <h3>Page 4</h3>
                    <p id="page4caption">Page 4 Page 4m doPage 4or Page 4 amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod <br> luctus tristique. Proin vel consectetur feugiat
                        sed adipiscing.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <button data-target="page1" class="btn btn-primary c-btn" id="btn-1" >Page 1</button>
                    <button data-target="page2" class="btn btn-primary c-btn" id="btn-2" >Page 2</button>
                    <button data-target="page3" class="btn btn-primary c-btn" id="btn-3" >Page 3</button>
                    <button data-target="page4" class="btn btn-primary c-btn" id="btn-4" >Page 4</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your needs are, but it sounds like `jQuery` may be what you're looking for. It's a `javascript` library that's specifically designed to make tasks like this simpler.

Here I'm using the `click` and `toggleClass` methods to toggle the styles.

Hope this helps!

```js
$("#example").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("foobar");
})
```

```css
#example {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.foobar {
  color: coral;
  border: 2px solid coral;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">Click Me</div>
```

Edit: For this and any other `jQuery` to work, you must reference the `jQuery` library in your `html`. If you use a cdn, simply place the following between the `<head>` tags of your html:

```
 <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```