# Show a div and hide another clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a booking system where a user will land on the booking page and prompted for a date/time selection. When they click the button I want my landing page image (contained in a `div`) to be hidden and the available seats (also in a `div`) to appear in the same place. I found some code on this thread [How to hide one div and show another div using button onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981198/how-to-hide-one-div-and-show-another-div-using-button-onclick). But what happens is that the image never appears from the start the screen is just blank, the second `div` however does appear so it's just the first `div` I'm having the problem with. Code is below, any help would be great.

**JS:**

```
function switchVisible() {
    if (document.getElementById('seatspic').style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById('seatspic').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('seats').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('seatspic').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('seats').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="seats" style="display: none;">
    <?php echo $chart; ?>
</div>
<div id="seatspic">
    <img  style="display: block;" src="img/UCCBooking.jpg">
</div>

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onClick="switchVisible()">Check Availability</a>
```

Comment: Is the page a PHP page? You have `<?php echo $chart; ?>` so what does that output?

Comment: are you sure you don't just have a broken image reference?

Comment: yeah its a php page and that outputs the available seats, that works fine. the sole issue is the aesthetics of it really. And yeah no broken image reference, I added the image outside of the div to check that and it appears fine. My guess is that i'm double blocking the 'seatspic' div but I dont know where..

Comment: check  the initial value of document.getElementById('seatspic').style.display in the method switchVisible like this alert(document.getElementById('seatspic').style.display). You might get an empty string on the first call

Comment: Toggle a class, so much easier

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there, but I have also tried setting the display of the second div to block also to try force it through but also not luck.

Comment: how would I go about toggling a class epascarelo?

Comment: Start with taking out the inline style on the `img` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic idea on how to use a class to toggle two elements.

```js
function switchVisible() {
    document.getElementById("wrapper").classList.toggle("open");
}
```

```css
#wrapper #seats,
#wrapper.open #seatspic{
    display : block;
}

#wrapper.open #seats,
#wrapper #seatspic {
    display : none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="seats">
        Seats
    </div>
    <div id="seatspic">
       Pic
    </div>
</div>

    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onClick="switchVisible()" href="#">Check Availability</a>
```