# Toggle between divs: How to show only one div at a time?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two div's with different content. I managed to add show-hide div function when clicking on a button. The problem is, when one div is visible and I click on the second button, they are both visible. I would like to show only one div at a time - while one div is shown and I click on another button, the previous div should hide automatically.

I would not want to use jQuery, hope it's possible with pure JavaScript only.

```js
function horTxtFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("horTxt");
 if (x.style.display === "none") {
  x.style.display = "block";
 } else {
  x.style.display = "none";
 }
}

function verTxtFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("verTxt");
 if (x.style.display === "none") {
  x.style.display = "block";
 } else {
  x.style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="horTxtFunction()">Horisontaalne tekstiga</button>
<button onclick="verTxtFunction()">Vertikaalne tekstiga</button>

<div id="horTxt" style="display:none;">
<p>Some content here</p>
</div>

<div id="verTxt" style="display:none;">
<p>Some different content here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you click the button twice it shows and then hides target `<div>` is that expected behavior? Or, once either of the `<div>` is visible, you shouldn't be able to hide it until you click the button showing another `<div>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981198/how-to-hide-one-div-and-show-another-div-using-button-onclick/25981369

Comment: @Ilona : If my answer did solve your problem, you may accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider wrapping the two `<div>` tags in a controller `<div>` tag and then using "state" to control which child `<div>` will show.

In the example below I am using the attribute `dir` to hold the state and the CSS to play off the state and the children `<div>` classes.

```js
var holder = document.querySelector("[dir]");

function horTxtFunction() {
  holder.setAttribute('dir', 'hor');
}

function verTxtFunction() {
  holder.setAttribute('dir', 'ver');
}
```

```css
[dir="ver"] > :not(.verTxt),
[dir="hor"] > :not(.horTxt) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="horTxtFunction()">Horisontaalne tekstiga</button>
<button onclick="verTxtFunction()">Vertikaalne tekstiga</button>

<div dir="hor">
  <div class="horTxt">
    <p>Some content here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="verTxt">
    <p>Some different content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The major benefit of doing it this way is if you need to add additional children:

```js
var holder = document.querySelector("[dir]");

function toggle(val) {
  holder.setAttribute('dir', val);
}
```

```css
[dir="ver"] > :not(.verTxt),
[dir="hor"] > :not(.horTxt),
[dir="left"] > :not(.leftTxt),
[dir="right"] > :not(.rightTxt) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle('hor')">Horizontal</button>
<button onclick="toggle('ver')">Vertical</button>
<button onclick="toggle('left')">Left</button>
<button onclick="toggle('right')">Right</button>

<div dir="hor">
  <div class="horTxt">
    <p>Some content here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="verTxt">
    <p>Some different content here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="leftTxt">
    <p>This is the left text area</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightTxt">
    <p>This is the right text area</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I change to a single event handler and pass in the section I want to show. Then I had to extend the CSS to handle the new `<div>` tags. But now growing to more children is just adding the buttons, divs and CSS.

*UPDATE*

To hide all `<div>` tags first I made a minor change:

```js
var holder = document.querySelector(".holder");

function toggle(val) {
  holder.setAttribute('dir', val);
}
```

```css
.holder > div {
  display: none;
}

[dir=ver] > .verTxt,
[dir=hor] > .horTxt,
[dir=left] > .leftTxt,
[dir=right] > .rightTxt {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle('hor')">Horizontal</button>
<button onclick="toggle('ver')">Vertical</button>
<button onclick="toggle('left')">Left</button>
<button onclick="toggle('right')">Right</button>

<div class="holder">
  <div class="horTxt">
    <p>Some content here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="verTxt">
    <p>Some different content here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="leftTxt">
    <p>This is the left text area</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightTxt">
    <p>This is the right text area</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This hides all of the internal `<div>` tags and then only shows the correct one based on the value of the `dir` attribute. Since there is no `dir` attribute to start then no internal `<div>`s will show.

Comment: Thankyou, this is how I want it. Except, I would like to keep Divs hidden by default. Right now, first div is shown by default..

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to hide the other div and not just show the other.

```
function horTxtFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("horTxt");
var otherDiv = document.getElementById("verTxt");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    overDiv.style.display = "none";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    overDiv.style.display = "block";
}
```

}

Comment: This does not work. Opening one div still doesn't hide the other.

Comment: Perhaps you can try setting the visibility instead of the display. document.getElementById['horTxt'].style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById['verTex'].style.visibility = 'visible';