# Multiple buttons function to expand and hide div section with javascript

Tags: javascript, button, foreach, hidden-field

Hope everyone is having fun on this fun (or frustrating  like me) coding day. So, I came across a problem and was hoping someone could help guide me to the right solution. I want to set it so that when I click on the “read more” button, it adds the “active” class and would expand the paragraphs.
I was able to do a loop function for multiple buttons on the page, but when I click on one, it affects all the buttons. I know this is a looping problem but I have not figured out a way to solve it.
What I’m trying to do is basically only have the button I click on add the class, without it working on all the buttons on the webpage. I intend to add more buttons to the page, so if anyone has a better solution or knows of a looping method (cause I’m pretty sure the looping I’m using is the wrong way), please help.
Please see the video for what I mean when I click on one button, both buttons get affected by it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [why images of code are bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also, it sounds like you want an Accordion. Here is sample code for such. https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/accordion/accordion.html

Comment: Maybe try using an accordion. Yu can wrap up the data inside the accordion and achieve the functionality, rather than making more complex. Surf for accordion codes.

Comment: in this thread its prety well explained:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981198/how-to-hide-one-div-and-show-another-div-using-button-onclick